# how to bind data to a button text value in Angular8 material

Tags: angular, button, binding, angular-material, subscription

I need help with binding a data to a button text, any help please

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.summaryService.getSummaryAll()
      .pipe(
      take(1)
      ).subscribe(data => this.summary = data);
}
```

HTML

```
<button mat-flat-button  class="rectangle">
    <div class="external">{{ summary.tools }} </div>
</button>
```

Thank you

Comment: As it is async you need to use it like this: `summary?.tools`

Comment: nothing is displayed, when using summay.tools i have an error summary is undefined

Comment: @rezion what is the result of `console.log(this.summary)` in `subscribe()` method?

Comment: I have the data i just want to know how i can bind it to button text

Answer (score 0):

Eldar's comment above was the key... You can mock the behavior of an API call with delay from a promise or an observable or your API...

relevant **component.ts**:

```
export class ButtonOverviewExample {
  summaryPromise = {tools:''};
  summaryObservable = {tools:''};

  constructor(private srv:AppService){
    srv.getButtonTextViaPromise().then(
      (dataa:string)=>{ console.log(dataa); this.summaryPromise = { tools: dataa}; }
    )

    srv.getButtonTextViaObservable().subscribe(
      (dataa:string)=>{ console.log(dataa); this.summaryObservable = { tools: dataa}; }
    )
  }

}
```

relevant **service.ts**:

```
  getButtonTextViaPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("text from promise");
      }, 5000);
    });
  }

  getButtonTextViaObservable() {
      return of("text from observable").delay(5000);
  }
```

relevant **html**:

```
<button mat-button>{{ summaryPromise?.tools }}</button>
<button mat-button>{{ summaryObservable?.tools }}</button>
```

complete [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmkyeo)